# Dplyr error - Column must be length 1 (a summary value), not 10

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm getting an interesting error with dplyr.

```
Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `x_sum` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 10
```

I have created an example and tried to fix it. The fix is shown in the code below, and it works. However, when I use it on the real DF it produces the error. Any ideas? All codes below.

I tried rowwise() nil luck (produced all rows). I tried mutate but nil luck either.

```
loc <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc","aaa","bbb","ccc")
    wk <- c("5","5","6","6","7","7")
    a <- c("A","B","C","D","WKSH","WKSH")
    b <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
    c <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
    d <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
    e <- c(10,11,12,13,14,15)
    x <- c(0,1,0,0,5,5)


df <- data.frame(loc,wk,a,b,c,d,e,x)

Summary <- df %>% 
  group_by(loc, wk) %>%
  summarise(b_sum = sum(b), c_sum = sum(c), d_sum = sum(d), e_sum = sum(e), x_sum = ifelse(a == "WKSH", sum(x),0) ) %>%
  mutate(SumAll =  b_sum + c_sum + d_sum + e_sum)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. You group by `loc` and `wk` which for your sample data means that every group consists of exactly one row; so there is nothing to summarise here because every sum has just one term.

Comment: Try this `x_sum = sum(ifelse(a == "WKSH", x, 0))` instead of what you have in your code above.

Comment: thanks AntoniosK, it worked like magic.